# How to parse a JSON array string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an JSON array like this

```
  var filter_value_data = [{"Status":[{"name":"Open","id":"1"},{"name":"Pending","id":"2"},{"name":"Resolved","id":"3"},{"name":"Closed","id":"4"},{"name":"Evaluation","id":"5"}]},{"Payment Status":[{"name":"Paid","id":"10"},{"name":"UnPaid","id":"11"},{"name":"Part Paid","id":"12"}]},{"Priority":[{"name":"Low","id":"6"},{"name":"Medium","id":"7"},{"name":"High","id":"8"},{"name":"Urgent","id":"9"}]}]
```

I have tried filter_value_data["Status"] which is obviously wrong. How do I get the JSON elements for `Status` using the names like `Status,Payment Status`?

Comment: This is not a JSON string, it's a JavaScript (array) literal.

Comment: @Aravind: Let me know whether the answer is what you expected or not.

Comment: I've downvoted as you did not reply to or vote upon most of the answers below. Would you consider accepting one, and voting on any that you believe deserve it? This is how we thank people for their efforts on this site.

Answer (score 2):

`filter_value_data` is an array (having `[]`), so use `filter_value_data[0].Status` to get the first element-object with property `"Status"`.

It is always good to format your code in order to see the hierarchy of the structures:

```
var filter_value_data = [
    {
        "Status": [
            {
                "name": "Open",
                "id": "1"
            }, {
                "name": "Pending",
                "id": "2"
            }, ...
        ]
    }, {
        "Payment Status": [
            {
                "name": "Paid",
                "id": "10"
            }, ...
        ]
    }, {
        "Priority": [
            {
                "name": "Low",
                "id": "6"
            }, ...
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: I want to extract like `filter_value_data["Status"]`. I have a list of all such names. They are dynamic. I have a set of those names as well.

Answer (score 0):

With your current JSON you can't get the elements with the name alone.

You can get Status with `filter_value_data[0]['Status']` and Payment status with `filter_value_data[1]['Payment Status']`.

This is because the keys are in seperate objects in the array.
In order to get them with `filter_value_data['Status']` you need to change your JSON to

```
var filter_value_data = {
    "Status":[
        {"name":"Open","id":"1"},    
        {"name":"Pending","id":"2"},
        {"name":"Resolved","id":"3"},
        {"name":"Closed","id":"4"},
        {"name":"Evaluation","id":"5"}
    ],
    "Payment Status":[
        {"name":"Paid","id":"10"},
        {"name":"UnPaid","id":"11"},
        {"name":"Part Paid","id":"12"}
    ],
    "Priority":[
        {"name":"Low","id":"6"},
        {"name":"Medium","id":"7"},
        {"name":"High","id":"8"},
        {"name":"Urgent","id":"9"}
    ]
};
```

I wrote this on my phone so it's not as well-formatted as usual. I'll change it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code, it will return status object

```
filter_value_data[0]['Status']
filter_value_data[0]['Payment Status']
```

to get Single value you use :

```
filter_value_data[0]['Status'][0]['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current JSON, created a result which might be helpful for you.

JS:

```
$.each(filter_value_data,function(ind,val){
var sta = val.Status; // Status Object get displayed
    for(var i=0;i<sta.length;i++){
    var idVal= sta[i].id;
    var nameVal = sta[i].name;
        Statusarray.push(idVal,nameVal);
        console.log(Statusarray);
    }
})
```

[**FiddleDemo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2VvD8/)